# Map gowalla spot id or foursquare venue id to facebook place id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, geolocation, foursquare

I've heard about various place database mapping plans from the different providers, but is there anything currently that can resolve a Facebook ID from a Gowalla Spot ID?  Gowalla gives Foursquare ID, but not the Facebook ID.

Facebook place search is acting strange, and I already have the Gowalla and Foursquare IDs, so I'm looking for something that can resolve one of those to a Facebook ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I talked to Facebook about the venue harmonizing they do (those links on the left side of place pages) and they do not plan on making that available via the API.

The best available venue_id mapping solution I've seen so far was Factual's Crosswalk API: http://developer.factual.com/places/extended-attributes/#crosswalk

One month ago, we threw 5,172 foursquare venueIds (of restaurants in San Francisco) at Crosswalk and got back 1661 Facebook place ids.  So if you're looking for an answer 32% of the time you can try that =)  This is clearly a big problem and will continue to be for the foreseeable future.

Comment: At least Gowalla has made the decision for us now, so that's one less provider to harmonize.  Thanks for the tip on Crosswalk.

Comment: Hi guys, I work at Factual. Just wanted to let you know, we're constantly working to improve our data quality and density. @ggwarpig: thanks for the kind mention, and was wondering what language/platform you used to query Factual?

Comment: @dirtyvagabond We check back on occasion and have seen the dataset improving. For our tests we used php & couchDB.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has calculated a limited mapping between their locations and a number of other services (see the left hand column: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Shake-Shack/110574012366339).

To the best of my knowledge, they haven not made this mapping available via their API yet.

Foursquare has "[harmonized](https://developer.foursquare.com/venues/mapping.html)" with a number of partners, but not yet facebook.